# How can I send header info while calling rest service with below code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, http-headers

I need to send authorization header in the below code which I am using to call restful service. All works fine but header info is not getting sent.

```
services.factory('downloadService', ['$q', '$timeout', '$window',
    function ($q, $timeout, $window) {
        return {
            download: function (fileName) {

                var defer = $q.defer();

                $timeout(function () {
                    $window.location.href = 'lolo/download?fileName=' + fileName;

                }, 1000)
                .then(function () {
                    defer.resolve('success');
                }, function () {
                    defer.reject('error');
                });
                return defer.promise;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

I need to send below Authorization header -

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = $localStorage.authToken;
```

Comment: If this is about [tag:angular2] please don't add the [tag:angularjs] tag (also the other way around) to make it obvious about version your question is related to.

Answer (score 0):

you **can't pass header** while using `$window.location.href` but you can always use `cookies` for authorization.

Though I would suggest to have a look on [security problems with cookies](http://sitr.us/2011/08/26/cookies-are-bad-for-you.html) before changing anything on your server implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As @S4beR said, you can't pass header using $window.location.href.
A work around is to pass the token as query string or using cookie. However, those options suffer security problems.
Another approach is to request a temporary download token with a short lifetime, say 60 seconds. Then pass this download token as a query string in url.

```
services.factory('downloadService', ['$q', '$timeout', '$window', '$http', '$localStorage'
  function ($q, $timeout, $window, $http, $localStorage) {
    return {
        download: function (fileName) {

            var defer = $q.defer();
            var req = {
             method: 'POST',
             url: '/download/token',
             headers: {
                'Authorization': $localStorage.get('token')
             }
           }
            $http(req)
            .then( function (token) {
                $timeout(function () {
                   $window.open('lolo/download?fileName=' + fileName +"&token="+token, "_blank") = ;

                }, 1000)
            })
            .then(function () {
                defer.resolve('success');
            }, function () {
                defer.reject('error');
            });
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: shouldn't we avoid passing security token in a GET request? Any hacker can steal it and may lead to security issues even though the lifespan is 60 sec

Comment: That is  true. Depends on how much security the app need to provide, It is a work around if you can't use header or cookies.